# Publish from CircleCI to Dockerhub

Tags: docker, circleci

I am trying to build and publish images from CircleCI to Docker hub. When i checkin a code to a given branch the images should be built and published. Given below is the CircleCI config.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: /dockerapp
    docker:
      - image: docker:17.05.0-ce-git
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --no-cache py-pip=9.0.0-r1
            pip install docker-compose==1.15.0
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: |
            docker-compose up -d
            docker-compose run dockerapp python test.py
      - deploy:
          name: Publish application to docker hub
          command: |
            docker login -e $DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID $DOCKER_HUB_PWD
            docker tag dockerapp_dockerapp $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID/dockerapp:$CIRCLE_SHA1
            docker tag dockerapp_dockerapp $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID/dockerapp:latest
            docker push $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID/dockerapp:$CIRCLE_SHA1
            docker push $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID/dockerapp:latest
```

The last step "deploy" seems to be failing with the below message.

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
docker login -e $DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID $DOCKER_HUB_PWD
docker tag dockerapp_dockerapp $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID/dockerapp:$CIRCLE_SHA1
docker tag dockerapp_dockerapp $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID/dockerapp:latest
docker push $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID/dockerapp:$CIRCLE_SHA1
docker push $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID/dockerapp:latest
Flag --email has been deprecated, will be removed in 17.06.
Password: EOF
Exited with code 1
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

I had to correct a typo... the below line in the circle ci config.yml was missing the -p flag..

```
docker login -e $DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_HUB_USER_ID -p $DOCKER_HUB_PWD
```